# Expected processing time using mysqlimport for MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-18.04, mysqlimport

Started a mysqlimport call about 2.5 hours ago, loading appeared to stop about an hour ago (per a check on data_length and index_length within the information_schema), so I imagine indexes are being created at this point.

Can anyone provide guidance on how long imports of this sort normally take?  File to be loaded was a CSV file that was about 2.5GB on disk.  I have 16 gigs of RAM, but haven't seen RAM used exceed 8GB since it started; CPU usage spiked a while back, but appears to have subdued since.  The only possible hiccup is that I'm loading to a MySQL installation on an external HDD (due to space reasons), so occurs to me processing could be slower.

**Edit**:

```
mysql> show create table priceHist;
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table     | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| priceHist | CREATE TABLE `priceHist` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `ticker` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `open` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `dividends` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `unadjClose` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`ticker`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You could check on current reads and writes with this query -   
SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name LIKE '%reads%' OR 
variable_name LIKE '%writes%' OR variable_name = 'uptime' ORDER BY variable_name 
;    run again in 10 seconds and check your numbers.  External HDD or Memory sticks could be much slower than your HDD. SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table; would be helpful.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, added output of `SHOW CREATE` per suggestion.

Comment: If you would SET GLOBAL innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50; an hour before you want to load your 2.5GB CSV input it would expedite ingestion of the data.  It will still take it time to get your rows from RAM to storage.  Next day if there will be no more CSV loads, put it back to 25 for 25% reserved for change management.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, thanks for this.  Any reason not to leave it at 50?

Comment: You could leave it at 50 percent.  Watch your innodb_data_reads rate per second.  If they do not increase significantly, leave it there.  View profile, Network profile for free downloadable Utility Scripts to determine RPS when curious.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, thanks!  Don't suppose you have a suggestion on a MySQL IDE, do you?  Had used Toad in the past on a Windows system, working on Linux now.  Considered Workbench, but would rather not pay for one (ie, not sure if it's worth it).

Comment: Workbench by MySQL is free.

Comment: You should have in your tool box, JetProfiler.com see our Links page for brief description.  Run it free as long as you want to identify Top Queries, Top Tables, etc and they have built in EXPLAIN query just by clicking, super tool.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, thanks for this.  I've DLed Workbench, but not sure what server/host name to use for a mysql installation housed on an external drive.  Any experience/ability to shed some light?

Comment: After you have your MySQL Command Prompt, SELECT @@hostname; to determine your 'server/host name'.  Let's use Skype, this is too many questions/comments for SO.